# Why using \mathrm still gives italic text?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, italic

I'm writing an equation using the `displaymath` environment, and I'd like to have the units in non-italic. So I use `\mathrm{}`, and I write this:

```
\begin{displaymath}
P_{AVG}=19.5 + \frac{2180}{5 \cdot 60 + 0.2} = 26.77~\mathrm{\mu}W
\end{displaymath}
```

But the units remain italic:

[image]

I tried to use the 'amsmath' package, but the problem remains. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using the `book` class in `pdflatex`:
    \documentclass[12pt, a4paper, titlepage, twoside, openright]{book}

EDIT: it took me a while to realize that the `W` was outside the `\mathrm` block, but the solutions are both very good.

Comment: We need to see your font set up, but if we assume standard Computer Modern then lower case Greek letters are only available in italic, as Knuth intended them for math typesetting only. You might want to look at my `siunitx` package for a 'wrapped up' way of dealing with the micro unit, or load something like `upgreek` to deal with this manually.

Comment: @JosephWright: I think I'm not using any special font setting, as I'm using the `book` class in pdflatex. I'll put this in the question

Comment: @JosephWright: sorry: I've put the package. Since I have many occurrences of `\mathrm`, can I directly replace them with `\si`?

Comment: In any case, the W should be upright too, and all the numbers in the equation should have their units too (unless they are dimensionless). I'm with Joseph, use `siunitx`.

Comment: @Jellby: I agree, and I've installed the package. But can I just replace all the occurrences?

Comment: @JosephWright: both answers are implementations of your comment, how do I give you the credits?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is my suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
P_{\text{AVG}} = \SI{19.5}{\micro\watt} + \frac{\SI{2180}{\micro\joule}}{5 \cdot \SI{60}{\second} + \SI{0.2}{\second}} = \SI{26.77}{\micro\watt}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(By loading the `amsmath` package, I can use `text` to typeset the "AVG" subscript in roman)

Comment: Uhm it looks very nice but it requires some work to convert all the occurrences...I'll do it later :)

Comment: @clabacchio It pays in the long run, when you decide (or someone asks for it) that you want "m·N" instead of "mN", for instance.

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\begin{document}

\[
P_{AVG}=19.5 + \frac{2180}{5 \cdot 60 + 0.2} = 26.77~\upmu W
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this, it makes the job simple :) but how can I get the W non-italic?

Comment: `\mathrm{\upmu W}`

Comment: ok, I just realize that I left the W outside `mathrm`, and I was assuming it was inside :)